# How to specify component for injecting an interface using @Binds in hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, interface, dagger-hilt

If we are trying to inject the following class,

```kotlin
class NoComponentRequiredClass @Inject constructor(){}
```

we can inject it without specifying any component for it to be installed in.

However, if we are trying to provide a dependency as an implementation of an interface, we have to create a Module and subsequently have to specify the component we are trying to installIn.

For example:

```kotlin
interface Test{ 
  fun test() 
}

class TestImpl : Test{
    overide fun test(){}
}

@Module
object Module{
  @Binds
  fun providesTest(test:TestImpl) : Test
}
```

Along with it I have to specify the component we are injecting it on.

I was hoping to inject it without specifying the component (As NoComponentRequiredClass can be injected without specifying component).

How to inject Test without specifying component or in which component is NoComponentRequiredClass injected in?